# Find the range in which the number belongs, from a range string

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes as shown below:

```
[{:id=>1, :text=>"1-10"},
 {:id=>2, :text=>"11-50"},
 {:id=>3, :text=>"51-200"},
 {:id=>4, :text=>"201-500"},
 {:id=>5, :text=>"501-1000"},
 {:id=>6, :text=>"1001-5000"},
 {:id=>7, :text=>"5001-10000"},
 {:id=>8, :text=>"10000+"}]
```

Given a number, I have to find out in which hash this belongs to, and get the value of text for that hash. The output should be something like:

```
test(7000) # => "5001-10000"
test(700) # => "501-1000"
test(321) # => "201-500"
test(95) # => "51-200"
test(501) # => "501-1000"
test(20000) # => "10000+"
```

I can achieve the solution with the conventional `map`, `split`, and `select` method combinations. But, I just want an efficient solution.

Comment: Surely you have been around long enough to know thats not how stackoverflow works.

Comment: May be you need what I tried. I have tried and can achieve the solution with  the conventional map, split and select method combinations. But, I just want an efficient solution so posted in SO. Sorry for not posting my attempt.

Comment: @DickieBoy seriously..... no. Code Review reviews code.... where's the code here?

Comment: @rolfl touche. Though i was referring to the comment above.

Comment: @DickieBoy Seriously, how can you think *GimmeTehCodez* is appropriate for **any** SE site

Comment: Firstly... read my first comment, then read the comment in reply, the solution has been achieved, but @Vamsi wants a more effecient way. Which is why I gave the codereview SE.

Comment: @DickieBoy As it stands, this question is *GimmeTehCodez*. That may not be what the OP intended, but unless you point that out when you recommend CR (which you did not), then that's what it is and how it will (probably) remain.

Comment: I don't think this is just an usual question to mention my effort in the question. I definitely know how SO works. I just wanted to make sure that the answers are not just a correction of my code. I need answers with all possible approaches, unbiased solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
▶ CHECKER = [{:id=>1, :text=>"1-10"},
▷   {:id=>2, :text=>"11-50"}, 
▷   {:id=>3, :text=>"51-200"}, 
▷   {:id=>4, :text=>"201-500"}, 
▷   {:id=>5, :text=>"501-1000"}, 
▷   {:id=>6, :text=>"1001-5000"}, 
▷   {:id=>7, :text=>"5001-10000"}, 
▷   {:id=>8, :text=>"10000+"}] 
▶ def test input, checker = CHECKER
▷   checker.map do |r| 
▷     instance_eval(r[:text].sub(/\+$/, '-Float::INFINITY').sub(/-/, '..'))
▷   end.detect do |r| 
▷     r === input
▷   end.to_s.sub(/\.+/, '-').sub(/\.\.Infinity/, '+')
▷​ end
▶ test 700
#⇒ "501-1000"
```

The approach above will work for any `checker` intervals while they conform the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this way you just needed to add your final range value like `10000+`  `pa` is arrary

```
 pa = [{:id=>1, :text=>"1-10"},
 {:id=>2, :text=>"11-50"},
 {:id=>3, :text=>"51-200"},
 {:id=>4, :text=>"201-500"},
 {:id=>5, :text=>"501-1000"},
 {:id=>6, :text=>"1001-5000"},
 {:id=>7, :text=>"5001-10000"},
 {:id=>8, :text=>"10000+"}]
```

**Method**

```
def test(number)
    arr = pa.select{|a| a[:text] if  (a[:text].split("-")[0].to_i <= number && a[:text].split("-")[1].to_i >= number) || (a[:text].gsub('+','').to_i >= 10000 && a[:text].gsub('+','').to_i <= number)}
    puts (arr.first[:text] rescue "not in given range")
end
```

if you are not aware of final range then you can find it as. for any type of intervals

```
def test(number)
       final_value = pa.select{|a| a[:text] if a[:text].include? "+"}.first[:text]
        arr = pa.select{|a| a[:text] if  (a[:text].split("-")[0].to_i <= number && a[:text].split("-")[1].to_i >= number) || (a[:text].gsub('+','').to_i >= final_value.gsub('+','').to_i && a[:text].gsub('+','').to_i <= number)}
        puts (arr.first[:text] rescue "not in given range")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def test (number)

myranges = [{:id=>1, :text=>"1-10"},{:id=>2, :text=>"11-50"}, {:id=>3, :text=>"51-200"}, {:id=>4, :text=>"201-500"}, {:id=>5, :text=>"501-1000"}, {:id=>6, :text=>"1001-5000"}, {:id=>7, :text=>"5001-10000"}, {:id=>8, :text=>"10000+"}]
 if number < 1
    "Not in range"
 elsif number > 10000
    "10000+"
 else
    myranges[0..-2].select{|a|  p a[:text] if eval(a[:text].split('-').join("..")).include?(number)}
 end
end

> test 7000
#=> "5001-10000"
> test 0
#=> "Not in range"
> test 20000
#=> "10000+"
```